# Display issue on the "Select your next badge" (Silver Tab)

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

I would like to highlight an issue with the **Select your next badge** pop up. When I navigate from the "Gold" tab to the "Silver" tab I get a layout/display issue (screenshot below). I do not have any layout issues when navigating from any of the other tabs.

*Screenshot:*

[image: Select Badge Pop Up]

I am on Windows 7, using IE11.

Comment: I can reproduce on IE11 with Win7 too, works fine on Chrome (64.0.3282.119) and Firefox (57.0.4) though. I get the issue when on the Gold tab, and when navigating from Gold to any other tab. Starting on a different tab doesn't produce the same bug though (e.g. Gold -> Bronze squashes everything like your image, but Silver -> Bronze displays fine).

Comment: Migrate from IE11 to Chrome latest version.

Comment: I can't wait for [October 14, 2025](http://www.allyncs.com/docs/lifecyclesupport.html)

Comment: It is known as Internet Exploder for a reason :)